# jQuery Validation Plugin error outside a div

Tags: jquery, validation

I am building the validation plugin in my form and everyting is working well. But on checkboxes I get this as HTML:

**Form Check HTML checkboxes:**

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="third-check" class="require-one error"><label for="third-check">Check off</label></div>
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="fouth-check" class="require-one"><label for="fouth-check">Check off</label></div>
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="five-check" class="require-one"><label for="five-check" class="">Check off</label></div>
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="family" value="" id="six-check" class="require-one">
    <label for="checks" generated="true" class="error">Please check at least one box.</label>
    <label for="six-check">Check off</label></div>
</div>
```

As you can see the error is not standing outside the custom checkbox div. How can i do this?

**The JS:**

```
$.validator.addMethod('require-one', function(value) {
    return $('.require-one:checked').size() > 0;
}, 'Please check at least one box.');

var checkboxes = $('.right .require-one');
var checkbox_names = $.map(checkboxes, function(e, i) {
    return $(e).attr("name")
}).join(" ");

$(".valid").validate({
    meta: "validate",
    groups: { checks: checkbox_names },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox") 
        error.insertAfter(checkboxes.last());
    else
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 error.insertAfter(element.parent());
```

because you want to add the message after the div (which is the parent) to the current element.

UPDATE: after chat discussion, the correct anser is:

```
error.insertAfter(element.parent().siblings().last());
```

Comment: This is not working i think it must be on the error.insertAfter(checkboxes.last()); but that i get not working...

Comment: where does it place the error message if you use the element.parent() instead of checkboxes.last()?

Comment: Outside the costum-checkbox div but then the error is standing as second item and not at the last thing... so then i have: Checkbox, Error, Checkbox, Checkbox, Checkbox.

Comment: oh, i see, if you want the error to be the very last, ie "Checkbox, Checkbox, Checkbox, Error" then use `error.insertAfter($('.custom-checkbox').last())`

Comment: Hi Robert, Thats true. But i have multiple sections of .right with checkboxes in it... and then the error comes not on that right section where you dont havent checked a box. But alwasy at the last checkbox on the page... (I hope you understand)

Comment: thats a bit tricky, post more html code. Or look at a validation summary

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8638/discussion-between-robert-dondo-and-maanstraat)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this it worked for me. "optLocation" are checkboxes same as "family" in the above example

```
jQuery("#frmAddProducts").validate({                                  
    errorElement:'div',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {error.appendTo (element.siblings(".errordiv")); },    
    rules: { 
                txtProductTitle:{required: true}, 
                txtPrice:{required: true, number: true}, 
                optCategory:{required: true}, 
                optMainCategory:{required: true}, 
                txtProductImage:{required: true},
                optLocation:{required: true, minlength: 1},                 
                txtSummary:{required: true}, 
                txtDetails:{required: true}
            },
    messages: {
                txtProductTitle: { required: "Please enter a title" },
                txtPrice:{required: "Please enter a price",number: "Please enter only digits"}, 
                optCategory:{required: "Please select a sub-category"}, 
                optMainCategory:{required: "Please select a category"},
                txtProductImage:{required: "Please upload images"},
                optLocation: { minlength: "Please select a location", required: "Please select a location" },
                txtSummary:{required: "Please enter summary"}, 
                txtDetails:{required: "Please enter description"}
            },
    submitHandler: function() { fnAddProduct(); }

    });
```